# concat two array that is mapped in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mapping

I want to use the `useState` to store the value of the combined arrays. I am now getting the `one` and `two` array however I cannot concat both array into one. And I want to store them in a useState as well for me to map it later on a table.

```
const [samp, setSamp] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    // I am getting the values for this one.
    const one = referralCodes.map((data) => {
      console.log([data].join().split(","));
    })
    // I am getting the values for this one as well.
    const two = usedReferralCodes.map((data) => {
      console.log([data].join().split(","));
    })
    // and I want to concat both arrays and join them into one with single incrementing index value
    const combined = ([...one].concat([...two]))
    
    // this one prints
    console.log("one: ", one)
    // this one prints as well
    console.log("two: ", two)
    // this one returns undefined
    console.log("combined: ", combined)
    // I wanto get the combined Value and setState it so I can access it and display it on a table.
    setSamp(combined);
   
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can use spread operator`(...)` as bellow

```
let a = [{fname : 'foo'}]
let b = [{lname : 'bar'}]
let c = [...a, ...b] // output [{fname : 'foo'},{lname : 'bar'}]


let a = ['foo']
let b = ['bar','ab']
let c = [...a, ...b] // output ["foo", "bar", "ab"]
```

or when you map the arrays, push each in single array then at the end join both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need brackets around the mapped arrays when doing a concat.

```
const array1 = [1, 2];
const array2 = [3];
const result = array1.concat(array2); // Expect [1, 2, 3]
```

I'm not sure of what data `referralCodes` & `usedReferralCodes` contain, but another way for your situation is to create an empty constant array. And for loop push the results
Adapt the below logic to suite your need

```
const result = [];

// Use for...of instead of map and push result
for (const data of referralCodes) {
   const tmp = [data].join().split(",")
   result.push(tmp);
}
for (const data of usedReferralCodes) {
   const tmp = [data].join().split(",")
   result.push(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Hello, how can I console log the ``result`` into a one single array? I have tried your code and whenever I try console.log the ``result`` it gives me two array inside the ``result`` here's the print screen [console.log(result)](https://prnt.sc/l_maYBwKletE)

Comment: and this is the code that I used ( your code ) when running the code.
```// Use for...of instead of map and push result
  for (const data of referralCodes) {
    const tmp = [data].join().split(",");
    console.log("avail tmp: ", tmp);
    result.push(tmp);
  }
  for (const data of usedReferralCodes) {
    const tmp = [data].join().split(",");
    console.log("used tmp: ", tmp);
    result.push(tmp);
  }
  console.log("result: ", result);```